# C++ DLL for Excel not able to work on other computer

Tags: c++, excel, vba

I built a C++ DLL, to be called from Excel-VBA, using Visual Studio 2017.  It works well on my computer with the DLL built by debug mode. When I try to use it on another computer without VS, it gives a run time `error 53 - file not found`. After some research on the web, I have tried to built the DLL under release mode. Now I'm getting run time `error 53 - file not found` on my pc with VS. The error message on the other computer is run time 'error 453 - cannot find DLL entry point'.

Comment: Are you familiar with the process how to register and interfaceing  a DLL for use in VBA ? If yes what did you do to do so? If you don't have a registration you might be interested about [Side by Side assemblies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side-by-side_assembly).

Comment: Did you remember to ship the compiler runtime (aka the Visual Studio redistributables) along with your program? Without the runtime libraries your program cannot run properly. That goes for *any* compiler, not just VS.

Comment: I am not a programmer by training, unfortunately not able to digest the reference you gave. It's actually a very simple DLL trying to perform some intensive simulations which take too long to do in VBA.

Comment: Tried the Visual Studio redistributables, and it's not working.

Comment: resolved, using dependency walker and find two DLL need to be add to sysWOW64.